# How can I test whether an incoming call is from Google voice or a direct call to my phone?

Tags: android

I'm interested in writing a simple Android app to block incoming calls that are not being routed through Google Voice. Is there I way to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google voice gives the option of caller id through from original caller, or caller id from Google Voice number.  The user could use the latter option, and the application would block, or dismiss, any calls not from that number.

Of course the downside to this option is there will be no caller id information for incoming calls.

Plus side is the phone will only ring for Google Voice calls.

Comment: I'm aware of this option, but I really want both caller ID and filtering out of non-GV calls. That's why I want to just write the app myself. I'm hoping there is some kind of signal in the incoming call that is available programmatically and can identify the call's origin as Google Voice versus something else.

Comment: I dont think what you want is possible right now.  But you may want to watch this open source project that is trying to bring GV control to Java.   http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/